# Pairing html tags using c#?

Tags: c#, html

Trying to create an HTML checker using c#, but I just can't figure out how to check if two HTML tags are correctly paired `<body></body>`. I managed to get all the relevant tags into a dictionary (the closing tags with `/` in front), in order as they appeared in the input. I also can check for opening tags that don't close (or vice versa).

But I can't figure out how to check if any pairs of tags are overlapping. E.g.

`<body><title></body></title>`

```
   |____________|
         |______________|
```

(there will be many many pairs)

TO CLARIFY, this question is about **pair matching**, not about everything else html, thanks!

Comment: [Did you try an XML Parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/)

Comment: If it is not an homework use a real html parser like HtmlAgilityPack. Since not every tag needs a closing one like `<p>`, `<hr>`

Comment: Even if it is homework, just use HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: Remember several html tags like li allow an implicit close tag or an explicit one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match pairs of tags (non-paired tags aside), consider the following:

- go from left to right, enumerating all tags;
- if you see an opening tag, put in on the stack;
- if you see a closing tag, check if the corresponding opening tag is on top of the stack; if yes - pop  it, otherwise report error;
- at the end, check if the stack is empty.

Let me illustrate the idea using brackets instead of tags for simplicity. The function checks if brackets `()[]{}` are properly balanced.

```
static bool CheckString(string s)
{
    var stack = new Stack<char>();
    foreach(char c in s)
        if("([{".Contains(c))
            stack.Push(c);
        else if(")]}".Contains(c))
        {
            if(stack.Count == 0)
                return false;
            char d = stack.Pop();
            if(d == '(' && c != ')' || d == '[' && c != ']' || d == '{' && c != '}')
                return false;
        }
    return stack.Count == 0;
}
```

Comment: AlexD, in an html, tags don't need to be balanced. Read about tags like  `<p>`, `<hr>` etc...

Comment: @EZI Then I misunderstood the request. I thought it is about tag matching. But still, the idea applies to "matchable" subset of tags in HTML.

Comment: AlexD, Sorry but no, `<hr> <div> <hr> </div>` is possible and valid.

Comment: @EZI This question is about tag matching (which I thought was pretty clear from the question... I'll clarify a bit more), because I already managed to deal with the other tags, and only need to work out how to match the rest (which is already in a ordered dictionary).

Comment: @EZI But `<hr>` has [no end tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp) in HTML, no?

Comment: AlexD, the question is not about *tag matching*. Read the first line. `Trying to create an HTML checker`. So, I am sorry, It is not correct event it is accepted.

Comment: AlexD, OP finally corrected the question, now your answer is valid. I remove my downvote. (But a -1 for OP for this ambiguous question  :) )

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to use something similar to a `stack` to achieve what you're looking for. Have the stack contain opening tags and only the top tag can be removed (so if any other opening tags have been added but not closed, you cant remove the one that is buried beneath).

Makes it easy to check if something has been closed or if its eligible to be closed. If its matching tag isnt on top of the stack, it can't be closed until you've closed the tags above it.

Comment: Read my comment under other answer.